# ubuntu wifi bug: john-Inspiron-15-3511 kernel: [] rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: timed out to flush queue 2

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, gnome

I have this wifi bug

```
john-Inspiron-15-3511 kernel: [] rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: timed out to flush queue 2
```

happening on my Dell inspiron 15 3000 after upgrading Gnome on Ubuntu 20.04. I was trying to avoid these 22.04 type bugs, I wonder if I can rollback, and it will be ok.

Comment: the title of your post does not match the question you asked